# Push notification with Parse & PHP

Tags: php, parse-platform, push

I have an Android App that receive Push notifications from PARSE.COM and work fine, now I want to send notifications from PHP and I have gotten this message ...
`{"code":107,"error":"Invalid JSON: m01011205"}`

Whats wrong, do you have any ideas?

This is my PHP code

```
   <?php

  $APPLICATION_ID = "my application id";
  $REST_API_KEY = "my api key";
  $MESSAGE = "Notificación de Prueba";

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $errors = array();
    foreach (array('app' => 'APPLICATION_ID', 'api' => 'REST_API_KEY', 'body' => 'MESSAGE') as $key => $var) {
        if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
            $errors[$var] = true;
        } else {
            $$var = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }

    if (!$errors) {
        $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
        $data = array(
            "channels" => "m01011205",
            "deviceType" => 'android',
            "data" => array(
                "alert" => $MESSAGE,
            ),
        );
        $_data = json_encode($data);
        $headers = array(
            'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
        );

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Parse API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if (isset($response)) {
        echo '<h2>Response from Parse API</h2>';
        echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($response) . '</pre>';
        echo '<hr>';
    } elseif ($_POST) {
        echo '<h2>Error!</h2>';
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($APPLICATION_ID, $REST_API_KEY, $MESSAGE);
        echo '</pre>';
    } ?>

    <h2>Send Message to Parse API</h2>
    <form id="parse" action="" method="post" accept-encoding="UTF-8">
        <p>
            <label for="app">APPLICATION_ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="app" id="app" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($APPLICATION_ID); ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="api">REST_API_KEY</label>
            <input type="text" name="api" id="api" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($REST_API_KEY); ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="api">REST_API_KEY</label>
            <textarea name="body" id="body"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($REST_API_KEY); ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="send">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to change the `"` by `'` here `"channels" => 'm01011205' `

Comment: Hi .... I have gotten the same error

Comment: By changing the `"` by `'` ??

Comment: Correct, I changed The " by '

Comment: No.... I have gotten with the same error

Comment: Use the method `json_last_error()` and see witch error you get, like shown in this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: Maraboc one question ... I have in code the json_encode function name and the sample says json_decode, I wrong?

Comment: its the same thing, because `json_last_error()` Returns the last error (if any) occurred during the last JSON encoding/decoding. look at the second sample !!

Comment: OKS ... I have gotten ... PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_last_error()

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the Parse framework to send push notification because there is a SDK to that and examples.

https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#push-notifications

e.g:

```
// Find users near a given location
$userQuery = ParseUser::query();
$userQuery->withinMiles("location", $stadiumLocation, 1.0);

// Find devices associated with these users
$pushQuery = ParseInstallation::query();
$pushQuery->matchesQuery('user', $userQuery);

// Send push notification to query

ParsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $pushQuery,
  "data" => array(
    "alert" => "Free hotdogs at the Parse concession stand!"
  )
));
```